# How to connect Bluetooth headset with laptop

Tags: 14.04, wireless, sound, bluetooth

I'm using a Dell Vostro 1015 laptop, running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have a Nokia BH-108 Bluetooth headset which I use with my Nokia device. I want to connect it with my laptop, but haven't been able to. Can anyone explain in simple plain English how to do that?

Comment: What bluetooth device is in the computer? `lsusb` might show it

Comment: Dont know. That's why I mentioned the computer type. How to find out the bluetooth device type ?

Comment: Open a terminal window by pressing CTRL + ALT + t and enter `lsusb`  Use the mouse or touchpad to highlight the results and use CTRL + ALT + c (different in terminal) to copy and then you can paste into your question

Comment: Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth

Comment: So is it blocked `rfkill list all` and see what modules are loaded with `lsmod | grep bluetooth`

Comment: 1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: What to do next ? What does it mean by hard & soft blocked ???

Comment: Try `sudo rfkill unblock all`

Comment: Thank u Jeremy31, everything's unblocked for now. I will test the headset in a while and get back to u. But I still didnt understand difference between hard block & soft block.. Please explain

Comment: hard block usually means disable by hardware switch, something other than the FN combo most of the time.  soft block usually means that the FN combo can enable or you can use `rfkill unblock all` to enable

Comment: You should be able to try the answer below once again

Comment: It's worth nothing that most mono Bluetooth Headsets use the Hands-Free Profile, which has limited bandwidth and voice quality. You may find it the quality inadequate for voice recording, skype, etc. compared to using non-Bluetooth headset (e.g. DECT, USB,  3.5mm). It will be similar to talking on an older cell phone.

Additionally, the reliable range will be limited to your immediate work area (probably about 20 feet)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is usually needed to use a headset or other audio device is a module for pulse audio. Open a terminal window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter

```
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

and then pair with the device.

It is an Atheros bluetooth that you might not have firmware for, so if the above doesn't work, first try

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

and reboot.

Comment: Failure: Module initialization failed

Comment: I tried, but, the terminal displayed : Failure: Module initialization failed